# Assistente Virtual em Python - Eficiência

Tags: python

Estou criando uma assistente virtual em Python, e quero que ela seja mais "humana". Quero que ela interprete a minha requisição, e não apenas compare o que eu disse com uma string. Portanto, minha dúvida é:

Para abranger todas as variações de uma requisição, como por exemplo, "**Vai chover amanhã?**" e "**Vou precisar de uma guarda chuva amanhã?**", é preciso uma condição if para cada requisição? Por exemplo:

```
if audio == "Vai chover amanhã?":
    checarClima()...

if audio == "Vou precisar de uma guarda chuva amanhã?":
    checarClima()...

outros if's...
```

Essa é a forma que os grandes assistentes virtuais (Siri, Google Now, etc.) são feitos ou há uma técnica, um modelo de código que seja mais eficiente e faça o que disse no início (interprete minha requisição, e não somente compare com uma string)?

Comment: Projeto bacana, o google usa inteligência artificial e processamento de linguagem para traçar o significado composto pelas palavras em uma frase, é um caminho árduo você vai precisar treinar uma base de dados, lembrando que o seu `if`demonstrado esta comparando áudio com uma frase rsrs, você sabe que não é bem assim que funciona né ? ao capturar um áudio geralmente você terá que transcreve-lo em texto antes, assunto muito complexo para um mero comentário lol

Comment: Sim, entendo que não é um assunto básico.
Na pergunta eu simplifiquei para fins práticos. O que eu tenho hoje, já transforma o meu áudio em texto, processa através dos if's, gera um texto que é transformado em áudio e é reproduzido.
O cerne da minha dúvida era como remover a infinidade de condições if's que um projeto desse teria, para uma abordagem mais eficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recebi alguns feedbacks de outras fontes:

Primeiro dê uma olhada no **NTLK** e aprenda sobre **Processamento Natural de Linguagem**. Aprenda sobre **tokenization** e **tagging** e acho que chegará em algum lugar.

Esse link contém um pouco sobre PNL (Processamento Natural de Linguagem):
http://xrds.acm.org/blog/2017/01/build-natural-language-processing-based-intelligent-assistant-using-python-easy/

Resumo do texto do link:

Pensando no macro do projeto, o fluxo é:

**1. O workflow de uma requisição**

Solicitação por voz > Módulo PNL processa > API

As APIs são os módulos que irão resolver a sua requisição (API de clima, API de busca, API de alarme, etc.)

**2. Tokenization**

Função do módulo NLTK que irá separar cada elemento (palavra) da requisição.
Requisição: "Irá chover amanhã em São Paulo?"
Requisição após Tokenization: ["Irá", "chover", "amanhã", "em", "São", "Paulo", "?"]

**3. Remoção de "Stop Words"**

Função do módulo NLTK para remover palavras irrelevantes para a requisição, no caso as palavras "Irá" e "em".
Requisição pós remoção: ["chover", "amanhã", "São", "Paulo", "?"]

**4. Tagging**

Tagging é classificar cada palavra como verbo, pronome, adjetivo, etc. Isso é importante para dar sentido à frase após a tokenization e remoção das stop words. O NLTK também tem um função que faz isso automaticamente, porém ainda não descobri se suporta português.

**5. Reconhecimento de Entidade Nomeada (Named Entity Recognition (NER))**

Também uma função do NLTK que irá quais palavras são nomes, lugares, organizações, etc.

**6. Chame as APIs**
Após tratar a requisição, ela deve estar classificada corretamente para que a API correta seja chamada. No exemplo, estamos perguntando se irá chover. A palavra "chover" deve estar relacionado à API de clima, portanto essa API que vai responder à nossa requisição.

Answer (score 4):

Eu Não ia responder essa questão rsrs, mas...

Vamos lá você quer algo legal pra brincar ? ou algo profissional ?

**Profissional** - Não tem pra onde correr, você vai ter que trabalhar com redes neurais, isso demanda uma Inteligencia Artificial bem apurada, tudo é segmentado, palavra por palavra, cada uma recebe uma determinada classificação gramatical (verbo, adjetivo, substantivos, pronomes, etc), isso vai separar toda sua frase em categorias gramaticais, posteriormente isso será usado para compor o contexto como um todo, é realmente algo complexo...

**brincadeira de criança** - No inicio da internet os buscadores existentes no fim da década de 90 não possuíam `IA` para interpretar uma frase digitada na busca, mas e ai como isso era feito? - [Levenshtein](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_Levenshtein) é a resposta, um algoritmo muito utilizado para encontrar palavras próximas/semelhantes, por exemplo se uma pessoa digitasse "abacachi" como saberíamos que ele quis dizer "abacaxi" ? Levenshtein faz isso, ele calcula a distancia minima entre duas palavras, imagina no seu exemplo:

```
"Vai chover amanhã?"

"Vou precisar de uma guarda chuva amanhã?"
```

Imagina que no seu sistema você só tenha uma base conhecendo a palavra `chuva`, `temperatura` e `clima` ou seja apenas três palavras para definir uma ação para previsão do tempo, como essas três palavras no seu pequeno banco entenderiam essas suas frases ?

R: Segmente todas as palavras e aplique o algoritmo de  Levenshtein em cada palavra, na primeira frase você vai ter uma ótima pontuação da palavra `chover` quando comparada com a palavra do seu banco `chuva`, ou seja a palavra chover vai se destacar como a melhor pontuação em relação as outras palavras da frase, isso já te dá pistas que sua frase talvez tenha haver o com clima e você poderia tomar uma ação dependendo das pontuações das outras palavras dessa frase. O mesmo acontece para a frase seguinte que vai ter uma distância igual a `0` retornado pelo algoritmo é claro as duas palavras são iguais...

Veja os resultados esperados para Levenshtein para a sua primeira frase:

```
chuva => vai = distancia de 4     
chuva => chover = distancia de 3 
chuva => amanhã = distancia de 6
```

Menor distância é a palavra `chover` é uma excelente pontuação para uma palavra com com 6 caráteres, repara na palavra `vai` a palavra só tem 3 carácteres mas tem distância de 4, podemos dizer que ela é completamente diferente da palavra chuva e tem que ser descartada mesmo logo de cara, deu pra pegar a ideia de como tudo funciona/funcionava, esse algoritmo ainda é muito usado ...

Comment: Ótima resposta. Certamente não penso em fazer algo profissional a ponto de comercializar, mas o mais eficiente possível a ponto de realmente ser um assistente dentro da minha casa, com funções que realmente me economizem tempo como uma ida ao meu computador (como por exemplo perguntar algo da cozinha, ou pedir para tocar uma música, etc.). Isso pode ser feito de forma bem básica, com um monte de if's, mas já que estou fazendo quero fazer o mais eficiente e direito que o meu tempo me permitir.

Comment: Para quem está acompanhado e também curioso, respondi a minha própria pergunta com um link bem interessante, onde demonstra e ensina o processo de segregação da frase, remoção de palavras irrelevantes e classificação das palavras.

Comment: sim vc pode usar isso para ganhar velocidade e não submeter palavras irrelevantes para ter uma pontuação pelo algoritmo de Levenshtein

Comment: O postgres suporta o pgsimilarity. Pode ser uma boa para testar o Levenshtein. Fiz uns testes há uns anos e ficava bem mais rápido correr direto na base de dados. http://pgsimilarity.projects.pgfoundry.org/

Comment: @loops sim com certeza, seria muiiiiitooo mais rápido

Answer (score 2):

Uma assistente virtual depende de uma série de tecnologias bem mais complexas como [AI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelig%C3%AAncia_artificial), [machine learning](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizado_de_m%C3%A1quina) ou [análise de sentimento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis).

A Siri, por exemplo, nasceu de um projeto chamado [CALO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALO). O que eu sugiro é começar por utilizar algum tipo de tecnologia já testada como o [Haven on Demand](http://www.havenondemand.com/) da HP, que até tem suporte para Português, o que é raro neste tipo de projetos.

Tem um plano gratuito, se quiser testar, pois eles até providenciam a funcionalidade de Speech Recognition. Pode ver mais [aqui](https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, loops. Bem interessante esse Haven on Demand, com certeza irei estudar a fundo, porém eu quero criar o meu (mesmo sabendo que não chegará num nível desses), primeiro porque eu gosto pra caramba de criar automações e coisas do tipo e segundo porque ai eu posso falar que foi eu quem fez.

Comment: @DenisCallau Nesse caso, pode começar por aqui. http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/. textblob é uma ferramenta bacana em Python para trabalhar com nltk.